# Command to copy a file to another directory?

Tags: c#

I do this code to copy a file to another destination, but i need the his name ( to the copied file) with the date and hour of my PC ... what's wrong ??

```
string fileToCopy = "d:\\pst\\2015.pst";
string destinationDirectory ="C:\\Users\\pierr_000\\Desktop\\New folder (3)\\ba-{0:MM-DD_hh-mm}.pst";

File.Copy(fileToCopy, destinationDirectory + Path.GetFileName(fileToCopy));
```

Comment: Why would a directory have a .pst extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code.

1. Your format string is incorrect. The day of month is represented by `dd` not `DD`.
2. You aren't using your format string in any meaningful way.
3. You are concatenating strings rather that using [`System.IO.Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to construct paths.

It looks like you're trying to do the following:

```
string fileToCopy = @"d:\pst\2015.pst";
string destinationDirectoryTemplate =
    @"C:\Users\pierr_000\Desktop\New folder (3)\ba-{0:MM-dd_hh-mm}";
var dirPath = string.Format(destinationDirectoryTemplate, DateTime.UtcNow);
var di = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
if(!di.Exists)
{
    di.Create();
}
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileToCopy);
var targetFilePath = Path.Combine(dirPath, fileName);
File.Copy(fileToCopy, targetFilePath);
```

Comment: tnxx a lot , but  .. i need the users choose the destination ... how can i do that ?

Comment: @PieroChankji I suggest opening a new question rather than turning this one into a [chameleon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because `destinationDirectory`  is referring to a file. Use  [Path.GetDirectoryName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx) to retrieve the actual directory and [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) to combine paths.

```
 File.Copy(fileToCopy, Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(String.Format(destinationDirectory, DateTime.Now)), Path.GetFileName(fileToCopy)));
```

Comment: check the update, you've forgot to format the datetime